# Movement to the closing parenthesis from inside block

Tags: vim, parentheses, motion, cursor-position

I want a movement to get from point 1 to points 2 and 3:

```
FunctionCall(a, b, c, AnotherFunc(a, b))
            ^ <---  ^   ------------>  ^
            3       1                  2
```

Ideally it would work with editing operations like `d`, `y` etc

Now I count closing parentheses visually and use `<n>f)`, but it's very annoying.

Vim does have facilities to know about blocks, i.e. `i(`, `a(`, but I want 'a half' of such a command.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I usually do is using a suitable commands from `various-motions`.

For example, for your particular case `])` followed by `%` will help.

They can be combined with operations like `d`, `y` and `c`.

More details using `:help various-motions`

Comment: oh-oh-oh-oh-oh-oh
Somehow those lines I COMPLETELY missed while reading documentation :( A silly question now isn't it?
Thanks!

Comment: But why 'followed by `%`'? I just use `[(` then?

Comment: Less typing in case of `%`

Answer (score 2):

You are right that the *text objects* have knowledge about both sides of the block. If you briefly go into visual mode, your cursor will end up on the end of the range (`va(<Esc>`) or the beginning (`va(o<Esc>`) when using the `v_o` command to switch to the "other" side of the selection.

Unfortunately, because this involves multiple steps, it only works for navigation, but not as an atomic `{motion}` to be used with `d`, `y`, etc. You could write a custom motion for those, though. For example:

```
onoremap ,) :normal! va(<C-v><Esc><CR>
onoremap ,( :normal! va(o<C-v><Esc><CR>
```

These then work like motions, e.g. `gU,)` uppercases the text from the cursor to the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you elaborate on "write a custom motion". At least some pointers maybe so I can dig and write an answer if you don't have time?

Comment: Basically, just some `:omap`s. I've added a demo to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The normal mode command `%` will take you to the next opening paren (and while there, toggling between the opening and closing parentheses). So sadly it would jump to the innermost opening paren instead of place `2` or `3`.

Couple that with a `F(` and you've got something remotely neat that doesn't involve counting. So in place `1`, `F(%` would take you to place `3` and a subsequent `%` would jump you to place `2`.

Comment: doesn't work in more parenthesized cases like `Function(a, b, c, Distraction1(), d, e, More(Distractions()))`. I would want to move from position `d` to the first and last `(` of the `Function`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,) :normal! va(<c-v><esc><cr>
nnoremap <silent> ,( :normal! va(o<c-v><esc><cr>

onoremap ,) :<c-u>normal! mava(o`a<cr>
onoremap ,( :<c-u>normal! mava(`a<cr>
```

Note that for the motion version (`onoremap`), it consumes the `a` mark, which can be a problem; so it could be improved.